# why vscode does not run in jetson after instalation?

Tags: nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm trying to run my code on jetson NX5, but even after **installation** of it, it won't run.
even tried this command but still, have the same problem.

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode.git
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

A previous version, e.g. 1.50.0 started without error.

```
wget https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.50.0/linux-deb-arm64/stable -O stable.deb

sudo dpkg -i stable.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

May be late reply, But, its worth replying for future reference:
Note: This trick works for me for AGX Xavier with JP5.0.1, hope this works for you as well with NX5.

There is a bug in the latest release of debian of Vs code for AGX Xavier.

As, @Ali, rightly mentioned, lower release of it i.e. 1.50.* works fine.

Ref:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/vs-code-can-t-launch-with-jetpack-5-0/213980